# Receiving binary image from client and saving it on server side

Tags: java, spring, html2canvas

I am working on a Spring-MVC application where for the clientSide I am using html2canvas function to take screenshot and then I would like to send it to server for further processing and conversion. I am posting the code for html2canvas below. So I have a controller mapping which can read byte array, but I am just unable to pass it to the server, I keep getting error(also displayed below). 
Finally, I would like to receive the binary image and save it in server side. Kindly let me know.

Error :

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

Html2Canvas code :

```
 $(".description").click(function(){

               html2canvas($('body'), {

                    onrendered: function(canvas) {

                        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                        $('<img>',{src:img}).appendTo($('#canvas-image'));

                    }

                    });
```

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping("/convertbase/{id}")
    public String convertbase(@ModelAttribute("notices") Notes p,@PathVariable("id") byte[] id,Model model){
         byte[] data = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(id);
        try {

            FileOutputStream imageoutfile = new FileOutputStream("/home/akshay/check.png");
            imageoutfile.write(data);
            imageoutfile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return "redirect:/note/listing";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, any pointers would be helpful. Thank you for your time.

New Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/convertbase/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String convertbase(@RequestBody String body){
         byte[] b = body.getBytes();
         byte[] data = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(b);
         try {

            FileOutputStream imageoutfile = new FileOutputStream("/home/akshay/check.png");
            imageoutfile.write(data);
            imageoutfile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return "redirect:/note/listing";
    }
```

Ajax request :

$(".description").click(function(){

```
       html2canvas($('body'), {

            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                $('<img>',{src:img}).appendTo($('#canvas-image'));

                $.ajax({

                      url: '../convertbase',

                      type: 'POST',

                      data:{image:img}

                });

            }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass an image in URL, right? So, in this case URL can be very long and the server just can not be able to parse such request. Regular solution is to send data using POST in request body.

Comment: Ok, How can I send the data through post? As this is the raw image saved on the client side. I am still unclear, should I introduce a new variable or something?

Comment: If it was a variable which I can take in a form, and then submit it I would have done that, I only have access to the binary data, which I tried to give through URL.

Comment: You can make POST request using $.ajax({...data: img, ... }); Checkout  [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Do I need to modify my controller for using the method mentioned in docs?

Comment: Yes, you need to access request body by `@RequestBody String body` parameter. And also you no longer need `@PathVariable` and you should to add `method = RequestMethod.POST` to `@RequestMapping`. Dont forget also set type of request to post in ajax call like: `$.ajax({type:'POST' ...`

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help, just one last question, I have modified the controller and creating the ajax request now. Can you please check the main post to see the controller(at bottom) I have added. Is that correct?

Comment: You also no longer need variable in path: `value = "/convertbase"`

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much...I have edited the main post to include the Ajax, when I am using that Ajax code, it says Network 404 error. Can you please tell me what it is. Thank you again. :-)

Comment: I can not see your servlet mapping, but I guess that problem in URL: `../convertbase`. May be it should be `/convertbase`? Anyway it depends on your mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64801/discussion-between-akshay-and-denis-borovikov).